# Ionic v3 aplicativo fechando

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic3

Tenho um aplicativo com uma tela de login e outra home, executo e depuro em um Samsung S6 Android api 23. Criei um novo projeto com api mínima 19 e máxima 28 e quando publiquei alguns aparelhos informaram q o app gerava diversos erros e fechava, baixei para versão do android máxima 27, mesma coisa, agora baixei para a versão máxima 26 e resolveu para alguns aparelhos, mas continua dando o mesmo problema em aparelhos com api 27+.
Em nenhuma das versões em laboratório o app apresenta nenhum tipo de falha, nem quando executa nem quando gero o release para publicação.
Já apaguei a pasta android, node modules e não há nenhuma indicação de erro em nada, posto abaixo minhas configurações, pois estou sem nenhuma idéia do que fazer para resolver o problema:

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.11.0 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 11 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (G:\android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10

```
  "scripts": {
"start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
"clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
"@angular/common": "5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.13",
"@angular/core": "5.2.11",
"@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
"@angular/http": "5.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
"@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/http": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.18.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.18.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
"@types/leaflet": "^1.4.4",
"cordova-android": "7.1.4",
"cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.0.6",
"cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
"cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.3",
"ionic-native-http-connection-backend": "^4.0.10",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"leaflet": "^1.4.0",
"rxjs": "5.5.11",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.29"
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.3",
"typescript": "~2.6.2"
"description": "An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
"plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
  "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
  "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
  "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
  "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
  "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {}
},
"platforms": [
  "android"
]
```

O que está me deixando desesperado é que não gera erros, somente quando o cliente baixa o aplicativo via PlayStore e no aparelho dele que é um Samsung S9.
Tenho ideia de que o problema possa estar relacionado a versões ionic/cordova/android mas não sei o que fazer.

Obrigado de antemão a todos q possam me dar uma luz.

Comment: Um erro que ocorreu comigo em celulares mais novos é quando eu faço uma requisição HTTP, pelo `HttpClientModule` do próprio Angular, e ele sempre me retorna um erro porque faltava uma certa configuração no `config.xml`. Caso queira saber mais, [veja aqui](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)

Comment: Ola Vinicius, obrigado por responder, eu tow usando este plugin: ionic-native-http-connection-backend, para fazer as requisições http, pq assim q comecei a aprender tive problemas para acessar api de terceiros, será esse plugin é incompatível com aparelho mais novos? Infelizmente o link q vc mandou está quebrado.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada rápida, e esse plugin utiliza o `HttpClientModule` quando ele não encontra o `@ionic-native/http` instalado. É possível que o mesmo erro que ocorreu comigo, possa ocorrer contigo. Sobre o link, é esse aqui https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6.

Comment: Vlw Vinicius, vou fazer as alterações e te retorno...

Comment: Vinicius vc é o melhor, era isso mesmo... show de bola...